# Does the Bladesinger's Arcane Strike class feature let you use a melee basic attack as a minor action twice?

Tags: dnd-4e

Let me clarify this question as much as possible because this will be somewhat of a 3-parter question. 
The Bladesinger's Arcane Strike level 3 class feature says:

> When you use a bladesinger daily attack power on your turn, you may make a melee basic attack as a minor action.

So how I understand it is "You can make 1 melee basic attack as a minor action on your turn when you cast 1 daily attack power."

This would be a correct assumption, right?

So the other question becomes: 
If I fire a bladesinger daily power, then make a melee basic attack as a minor action and haven't used my move action, then if I action point and fire a second daily attack power, would I be able to turn my move to a minor action and use it to do a melee basic attack a second time?

Finally, taking into the account above of whatever answer, what if I fire a bladesinger daily power and then action point and fire another bladesinger daily power?  Would I get only 1 melee basic attack as a minor action due to never using my melee basic between the daily powers or could I do 2 melee basic attacks as a minor action each (assuming both was after the 2 daily attacks)?

Comment: bladesinger is not an essentials charachter :)

Comment: I don't know.  It kinda functions as such depending on how you look at it.  Melee basic as its main thing with gaining special features at higher levels or changes/additions to the current ones.

Comment: Thats just the way 4e is going in general I believe.  They don't list the book under essentials when you filter

Comment: Well technically, the book is a campaign setting like Forgotten Realms or Eberron, just the player's guide and the DM guide kinda rolled into one.  But ya, I understand your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answer. Yes, you can convert your move into a minor and do a basic attack twice.  Assuming the rules you have given are all the relevant ones.

Second answer.  No, if you don't do the minor action directly after completing the daily, I believe you loose the opportunity to do so later.  The key word here is 'when' instead of 'after'

Comment: Wow.  Oops on my part.  I obviously didn't read what I wrote more thoroughly even though it made sense in my head.  What I meant to say at the end is: "Would I get only 1 melee basic attack as a minor action due to never using my melee basic between the daily powers or could I do 2 melee basic attacks as a minor action each (assuming both was after the 2 daily attacks)?" I'll update the post.  Although, if I'm right based on your answer, it would be a yes then, right?

Comment: Thanks for editing the post.  Ok, so this clears up about everything that I needed for the class.